# Length keep returning 1 instead of 0 when checking if span has a no value inside a table

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks if the span tag within a table has a value so I can hide a certain row, but my function is failing.

The length always returning 1. It is supposed to return 0 if `<span>` has no value and 1 if it has.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
       <table>
         <tr id="header" onload="hideHeaders();"> 
          <td><span>Location</span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="roadRow">
           <td><span>Road Name</span></td>
           <td><span id= "road"></span></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function hideHeaders(){ 

  var roadRow = document.getElementById('roadRow');
  var r = roadRow.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerText;  
  alert(r.length);        
  alert(r);

   if(r.length == 1) {
        alert("on if");
        document.getElementById('header').style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Comment: Use textContent instead of innerText

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with innerText (Chrome 43), it just alerts 0. Are you doing more in your code to change your page's state before this? I also can't find anything about "oraload" (maybe onload?), is that something specific to your page?

Comment: No, I am not doing anything..

Comment: It is returning 0. May be something else going wrong in your code.

Comment: Try copying the function in the console [here](http://taylor-crush.co.uk/jxtc/test.html) and seeing what you get. If you get 0, it's definitely some of  your other code.

Comment: Are there any other way to do this? sorry about the oraload it should be onload. Maybe traversing thru table cells??

Comment: I think I already have a clue, when I use roadRow.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML, the alert prompts the value &nbsp; so when I replace the checking e.g., if r == "" it fails because it has a value = &nbsp;

how am i gonna fix this &nbsp issue?